# Craigslist selenium diagnose what's happening

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

https://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/rts/d/san-francisco-new-mortgages-reverse/6908455741.html

How do I diagnose what's happening when I click the buttons "reply" -> "show phone number"?

There is this popup and loading button. I would like to see what is being sent from the browser to the server when clicking the first and second button. The source code is obviously changing dynamically so it is not practical to track by inspecting the source. I imagine there's a plugin or some tool to intercept or read the requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the requests using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), it captures http/https requests, and help you understand how to mimic the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome or Firefox you could open the console and simply see the network traffic generated by a button.

[image]

With your example, you can see there is a call to the API at the following address:

```
https://sfbay.craigslist.org/contactinfo/sfo/rts/6908455741
```

Once you analyzed it, you can script the behaviour with Selenium and grab the data.